# TinyMCE custom text rendering

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'd like to be able to set content like this:

```
<p>Here is an image: <img src="{filedir_1}/foo.jpg"></p>
```

And when the WYSIWYG renders it, I'd like to be able to replace that {filedir_1} with a base url. But I do not want to "replace" the content itself, meaning when I hit save, I expect {filedir_1} to still be there.

Any idea if I could do this? (TinyMCE 3)

Comment: I haven't tried anything, no idea where to even begin.